# user registration sends 2 emails

Tags: php, email, joomla

I am using a custom form, with a Joomla 1.6 Platform. The User email goes through fine, but the email notifing us of the sign up does not come through. Is it possible to send 2 emails back to back like this or is there an error in my code?

```
///----------------User Email After Registered----------------------------///
 // Send notification email //


 $to = $email;
 $subject = "$hs2 Alumni Football Team";
 $message   = "
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <h1>Alumni Football USA</h1>
 <p> Hi $firstname,</p>
 <p>You are now able to sign up for $hs2 games! Login to Reserve your spot!</p>
 <p>Username: $username</p>
<p>Password:  $showpass</p>
 <p>$hs2 Alumni Football Team Page---$remail2 </p>
 <p>This is an automatic Email, please do not respond/reply</p>
 </body>
 </html>
 "; 
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";  
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

 $headers .= 'From: Alumni Football USA<NOREPLY@alumnifootballusa.com>' . "\r\n";


 // Send notification //
 mail($to,$subject, $message, $headers);

///---------------Email site owner-----------------------------------------///



 $phone1 = $cell;

 $cell1 = formatPhone1($phone1);

 $phone2 = $home;

 $home1 = formatPhone2($phone2);


 $query = "SELECT t_name FROM " . $table_prefix . "bl_teams  WHERE id = ".$team_id;
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $hs2 = $db->loadResult();


 $query = "SELECT ((date_format(now(),'%Y') - date_format(birthday,'%Y')) - (date_format(now(),'00-%m-%d') < date_format(birthday,'00-%m-%d'))) 
  FROM " . $table_prefix . "users WHERE'".$email."' = username";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $age45 = $db->loadResult();



 $query = "SELECT t_city FROM " . $table_prefix . "bl_teams WHERE ".$team_id."= id ";       
             $db->setQuery($query);
    $city5 = $db->loadResult();


 $query = "SELECT s.s_descr FROM " . $table_prefix . "bl_seasons as s WHERE ".$s_id."= s.s_id ";        
             $db->setQuery($query);
    $state = $db->loadResult();




 $query = "SELECT u.email FROM " . $table_prefix . "users as u, " . $table_prefix . "bl_teamcord as tc WHERE tc.s_id = ".$s_id." AND FIND_IN_SET('$team_id',tc.teams) AND  tc.u_id = u.id AND 

 tc.reg_emails = 1";        
             $db->setQuery($query);
    $remail1 = $db->loadResultArray();


 if ($remail1){
 $remail = implode(",",$remail1);
 }else{
 $remail = "";}

 // Send notification email //

 $to = $remail;
 $subject = "***Reserved***$hs2,$state --$firstname $lastname";
 $message   = "
 <html>
 <head><title>Alumni Football USA</title></head>
 <body>
 <h1>$firstname $lastname</h1> 
 </body>
 </html>
 "; 
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";  
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 $headers .= 'From: Alumni Football USA <webmaster@alumnifootballusa.com>' . "\r\n";


 // Send notification //
 mail($to,$subject, $message, $headers);


///--------------------------------------------------------------///
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues as far as sending back to back I do it all the time.  There is more than likely something wrong in the code

Comment: Are you sure that `to` is being set properly?  Are you sure there is no error in the code that happens before the second `mail` is reached?

Comment: I will check again, I have been testing this half the day. Will advise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be you $to variable might not have email value:

```
if ($remail1){
    $remail = implode(",",$remail1);
} 
else{
    $remail = "";  //you might have this
}
$to = $remail;  //so if $remail is blank so will be the $to as well
```

So ensure your $to variable holds email,

```
if(!empty($to)) {
  //send email
  mail($to,$subject, $message, $headers);
}
```